# Malloc struct with double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    char* name;
    int count;
    Node **subnodes;
}Node;
```

I receive name and count over network one by one for the whole k-ary tree and then I reconstruct the tree. How do I malloc this struct?

```
Node *n = NULL;
fun(n, buf); //call function fun

void fun(Node *n, void *buf){
    //successfully extracted name and count from buf
    // say count is 5, i.e. this node should have 5 subnodes and 
    // name is root
    n = malloc(sizeof(*n)+strlen(name));
    n->name = name;
    n->count = count;
    for(int i=0; i<n->count;i++)
         fun(n->subnodes[i], buf+some_increment);
}
```

This crashes as soon as I call fun for the second time. How should I malloc properly? Should I be malloc-ing each subnode?

Comment: What is `count`? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is hard to say without seeing your other variables.

Comment: I understand that, but as I've commented in code, it's a value recieved from network and I verified it to be a correct integer. Putting all that code will unnecessarliy mess up the question.

Comment: You `received name and count over network` puzzles me.
Do you know what node points to/should point to? Also, at least in C++ don't use `NULL`.

Comment: @Ælex I received a name of the node and number of subnodes from buf. Now I need to construct the node and subnodes iteratively.

Comment: Do you have to use malloc? Is this for C or C++?

Comment: C. I'm sorry. I'll remove irrelevant tags

Answer (score 3):

First off, you realise this is leaky? `n` is just on the stack - you aren't returning it or "saving" the value you give it anywhere permanently.

Then you haven't actually allocated any memory for `subnodes`, so by indexing into it you are reading unallocated memory.

Without a more complete example it is hard to further, but at a minimum you need to malloc something for `subnodes`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will have to malloc each node.  I see a couple of issues here:

1. You are neglecting in `malloc(sizeof(*n)+strlen(name))` to provide space for the null terminator.  This statement should read `malloc(sizeof(*n)+strlen(name)+1)`.  Also you should set the name pointer in the struct to the end of the struct and then strcpy the buffered name to it

   `n -> name = (char *)(n + 1)
   strcpy(n -> name, buffered_name)`

   I presume the buffered version is transient.
2. You are allocating no space for the variable sized array of child nodes.  This has to be done as a separate malloc or you have to embed it in the Node malloc (I'd recommend placing it between the Node header and the name string content.

Note, I am making a few liberal assumptions about what the code really looks like since this is  clearly an incomplete snippit with typos.  e.g. subnodes <-> subnode

Addendum: Code snippet (untested so normal caveats apply):

```
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    int count;
    Node **subnodes;
}
  Node;

Node *fun(void *buf)
{
    ...
    //successfully extracted name and count from buf
    // say count is 5, i.e. this node should have 5 subnodes and 
    // name is root

    // Allocate space for the node and its data.
    Node *node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node) + count * sizeof(Node *) + strlen(name) + 1);

    // Set the name pointer and copy the name from the I/O buffer.
    node_ptr -> name = (char *)(node_ptr + 1) +  count * sizeof(Node *); // set the name pointer to the right location.
    strcpy(node_ptr -> name, name); // copy the buffered value to the node value.

    // Establish the count from the I/O buffer.
    node_ptr -> count = count;

    // Set the subnodes address.
    node_ptr -> subnodes = (char *)(node_ptr + 1);

    // Get the child nodes.
    for(int child = 0; child < node_ptr -> count; child++)
        node_ptr -> subnodes[child] = fun(buf + some_increment);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken. Can you please add a snippet or an example? Would I need to malloc n number of subnodes as well? Or when the function is called recursively, it will be done correctly with the malloc call?

Comment: The struct is from a library. i cannot modify the struct itself. So I am stuck with name at the beginning.

Comment: What is `n` then? Your terminology is confusing. In your code `n` is a Node, and now you are asking if you should allocate `n` subnodes? How many subnodes? Judging by the fact that the function `fun` (can't you make a better name?) is supposed to allocate things for its argument `n` you should at least pass that by reference.

Comment: @NickGammon Appreciate you spending time on the question and clarifying things but it would help not being too pedantic. Clearly, in the comment above, I mean how do I add `x` number of nodes to the newly created node. Also, I cannot show the whole irrelevant network code. I have a string and an int, that as I wrote in comment of code, is valid and I extracted it from buf.

Comment: I am seriously trying to help you but I can't even guess what you are doing, sorry about that. OK, we can allocate multiple sub-nodes. I presume you want `count` of them? But what goes into `name` and `count` in the sub-nodes? And since `Node` contains subnodes, do these subnodes also have subnodes? If not, what does `subnodes` contain then? NULL? If that is the case you may as well just put NULL into `subnodes` right now and not try to malloc the subnodes at all.

Comment: @KenClement Thanks a lot! Such an awesome explanation. Just one thing. What if I had to return the root, i.e. the first node? Since I am recursively going to subnode, how do I return the root?

Comment: Also, I am guessing, it is sizeof(*node_ptr) and not sizeof(*n) right?

Comment: Assuming the first node to be presented by the network I/O buffer is the root node (I have been presuming a root down presentation by the network stream), then the initial invocation of `fun` will return the root node.

Comment: @Neo - correct `sizeof(*node_ptr)`or even `sizeof(Node)` - the later being my favorite.

Comment: See my revised reply.

Comment: @Neo - I made a correction of an omission.  Further cleanup is possible but I'll leave that as an exercise...don't forget the check if you like it :-)

Comment: `Node *node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Node) + count * sizeof(n) + strlen(name) + 1);` - I don't agree this is correct. I tried that and it crashed. The `Node*` variable needs to have memory the size of `Node` allocated. Inside `Node` is **another pointer** which is `name`. That should be separately allocated enough room to hold the name and terminating null byte. Trying to do both allocations in one `malloc` is just wrong.

Comment: I corrected this to `malloc(sizeof(Node) + count * sizeof(Node *) + strlen(name) + 1)`.  You are correct.  The way I rendered it was erronous.  The statement that "Trying to do both allocations in one `malloc` is just wrong" is an opinion not a statement of fact.  Done with minimal care, it is semantically correct (strings should always go at the end to avoid alignment issues but other than that alignment issues are incredibly rare and will not in any case occur in this context.

Comment: Oh I see. You have made `name` point to the end of the struct. Ah well, there is more than one way of skinning a cat.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a structure that looks like this:

```
  typdef struct{
        char* name;
        int count;
        Node **subnodes;
    }Node;
```

Not really, because it is `typedef` not `typdef`.

As John3136 pointed out, your function allocates memory in `n` which is a local variable. Plus you are assigning `count` and `name` which do not appear to be passed to `fun`.

It also looks to me like the function `fun` will recurse indefinitely.

You call `fun` which (in the last line) calls `fun` which therefore calls `fun` again, and so on until you run out of stack.

---

*(Edited to add)*

Trying to guess what is wanted, I have got this working example going:

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char* name;
    int count;
    Node **subnodes;
}Node;

void makeNode(Node * &n, const char * name, const int count)
  {
  // make the node itself
  n = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(*n));
  // allocate room for the name
  n->name = (char *) malloc (strlen (name) + 1);
  // copy in the name
  strcpy (n->name, name);
  // save the count of subnodes
  n->count = count;
  // allocate memory for subnode pointers (not the subnodes themselves)
  if (count > 0)
    n->subnodes = (Node **) malloc (sizeof (Node *) * count);
  else
    n->subnodes = NULL;
}  // end of makeNode

int main ()
  {
  Node *node = NULL;
  makeNode(node, "foo", 3);
  makeNode(node->subnodes [0], "the", 0);
  makeNode(node->subnodes [1], "slithy", 0);
  makeNode(node->subnodes [2], "toves", 0);

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf ("Node %i, name = %s\n", i, node->subnodes [i]->name);
  printf ("Done!\n");
  } // end of main
```

This runs OK:

```
Node 0, name = the
Node 1, name = slithy
Node 2, name = toves
Done!
```

Note, I compiled with g++, not gcc. However it should give you some ideas to go on with.

*(You don't have references in C, so you really need C++ for this to work)*

Comment: Like I wrote in the question, `buf` gives name and count.

Comment: `void *buf` gives name and count? How?

Comment: This is a network packet. I extract it and I can assure you it gives right integer count and char *name. Assume you know count and name, how could this be done then?

Comment: I'm asking for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because there is a lot of to-ing and fro-ing trying to make sense of what you are doing. You don't have to put in the network code, just make something that compiles and demonstrates the issue.